# I am making a survey in python and i want to print a string but it keeps saying that it cant be called

Tags: python, string

I have done some research, but all the problems online seem to be with incorrectly made variables or incorrect `.lower()`, so I thought I would ask.
Here is my code. The line `print ('Here are your answers')` is the string that can't be called.

```
if age < 16:

           favorite_film = input ('What is your favorite film? ')
           print = ('Thank You')

           favorite_book = input ('What is your faavorite book? ')
           print = ('Thank You')

           family_number = input ('How many people do you live with? ')
           print = ('Thank You')

           print  ('Here are your answers')
           print  (name1)
           print  (name2)
           print  (town)
           print  (age)
           print  (favorite_film)
           print  (favorite_book)
           print  (family_number)

           print ('You are finished, you may now leave')

    elif age >= 16:

           bank = input ('What bank do you store your money at? ')
           print = ('Thank You')

           house = input ('What kind of accomidation do you reside in? ')
           print = ('Thank You')

           favorite_food = input ('What is your favorite type of food? ')
           print = ('Thank You')

           print  ('Here are your answers')
           print  (name1)
           print  (name2)
           print  (town)
           print  (age)
           print  (bank)
           print  (house)
           print  (favorite_food)

           print ('You are finished, you may now leave')
```

Comment: For the future, see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In general, code in a StackOverflow question should be the *shortest possible thing* that someone else can run (meaning it needs to work well enough to be runnable) to see the same problem; and the question should be precise about that problem, including the exact text of the exception or error.

Answer (score 1):

I made two changes:

1. Removed the `=` in lines such as `print = ('Thank you')`

By assigning a string value to `print` you overrode its meaning, and the interpreter probably showed you this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "string.py", line 14, in <module>
    print ('Here are your answers')
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

2. Moved `èlif age >= 16:` to the same indentation level as the initial `if` statement.

`if` and `elif` should always be at the same indentation level, even though they are tied together. Python3

```
if age < 16:
           favorite_film = input ('What is your favorite film? ')
           print ('Thank You')

           favorite_book = input ('What is your faavorite book? ')
           print ('Thank You')

           family_number = input ('How many people do you live with? ')
           print ('Thank You')

           print ('Here are your answers')
           print (name1)
           print (name2)
           print (town)
           print (age)
           print (favorite_film)
           print (favorite_book)
           print (family_number)

           print ('You are finished, you may now leave')

elif age >= 16:

           bank = input('What bank do you store your money at? ')
           print ('Thank You')

           house = input ('What kind of accomidation do you reside in? ')
           print ('Thank You')

           favorite_food = input ('What is your favorite type of food? ')
           print ('Thank You')

           print ('Here are your answers')
           print (name1)
           print (name2)
           print (town)
           print (age)
           print (bank)
           print (house)
           print (favorite_food)
           print ('You are finished, you may now leave')
```